Applying for France Business Trip Visa in Canada while on a Maintained Status
I am a foreign worker currently in Canada and was invited to a short business trip in France. I am on maintained status as my study permit has expired and I have received a WP-EXT for my Post-Graduation Work Permit (PGWP). I am awaiting my PGWP while my temporary visit visa remains valid for multiple entries. What document should I provide as proof of residence in Canada when applying for a France visa? Should I provide the temporary visit visa, the WP-EXT for PGWP, or both?
In addition, on the VFS Global appointment page, should I select “Business - Short Stay” or “Short Stay - Any Other Visa Category” under the visa category section?


What document should I provide as proof of residence in Canada when applying for a France visa? Should I provide the temporary visit visa, the WP-EXT for PGWP, or both?

France-visas.gouv.fr states that you meet the residence requirement if you are staying in the consular district for more than three months and you are legally present there. I couldn't find any more specific guidance but I think either document should be enough to establish that and I would submit both.

In addition, on the VFS Global appointment page, should I select “Business - Short Stay” or “Short Stay - Any Other Visa Category” under the visa category section?

Since it's a business trip, why not pick “Business — Short Stay”? VFS will probably use a checklist to check if you provided all the documents required for a business trip but ultimately, it shouldn't matter that much.

Thank you for your answer! I appreciate it :)
